# uriparser: how to build it?

Tags: c, uri

For my new project I decided to use [uriparser](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/) for query string parsing, because it is recommended on a lot of pages. Downloaded it but now I'm stuck. How am I supposed to build it? This wouldn't be the first build, but however, make says there is no makefile available. This leads me to thinking there might be something else, maybe it shouldn't be built? Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked in the README that's in the package?

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the distribution, and it seems that it's an autotools based.

So run `./configure` at the root directory, this will generate a makefile which you can execute by `make`.